# How to sort a list of lists when the lists and their entries are named?

Tags: r

I'm trying to order a list of lists by the first parameter, e.g.:

```
a <- list(sem = 23, do = 32)
b <- list(sem = 82, do = 12)
c <- list(sem = 1, do = 13)
d <- list(sem = 42, do = 13)

main.list <- list(a,b,c,d)
```

So that the result would be a main.list with its elements ordered as such: c,a,d,b

I've tried `sapply`, with no success, in this way:

```
main.list[order(sapply(main.list,'[[',"sem"))]
```

I know it works by calling the list entry by its position in the list:

```
main.list[order(sapply(main.list,'[[', 1))]
```

But I wanted to call it by its name, not its position.
The solution I found so far, in my very long lists, is to add a code bunch to find the position of a given named entry. I would like to avoid that extra code, and I thought I was using the sapply function wrong.

I would love some input on this.

Comment: `main.list[order(sapply(main.list, '[[',1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
theorder = as.data.frame (colA = lapply(main.list, "[[", 1)) %>%
arrange(colA)

main.list[names(theorder)]
```